# train xgboost model unbalanced data

Tags: r, xgboost

I am a newbie using the xgboost package, I am trying to create a model with the greatest accuracy, and that the sensitivity and specificity are balanced. The problem I have is that the base is unbalanced at about 1: 3 and the predictions give me a very low sensitivity.

```
data(cats,package = "MASS")
prop.table(table(cats$Sex))
        F         M 
0.3263889 0.6736111
```

plot the data

```
library(ggplot2)
ggplot(cats, aes(Bwt, Hwt, colour = Sex, shape = Sex)) + geom_point(size = 3)
```

[image]

load xgboost package

```
library(xgboost)

# Split data
set.seed(123);index <- sample(nrow(cats),size = nrow(cats)*0.75)
train <- cats[index,]; test <- cats[-index,]

train_x <- train; test_x <- test
train_x$Sex <- NULL; test_x$Sex <- NULL

# Convert predict variable in numeric
y_train <- as.numeric(train$Sex) - 1; y_test <- as.numeric(test$Sex) - 1
train_x[] <- sapply(train_x, as.numeric); test_x[] <- sapply(test_x, as.numeric)

# Construct xgb.DMatrix object from either a dense matrix
dtrain <- xgb.DMatrix(as.matrix(train_x),label = y_train)
dtest <- xgb.DMatrix(as.matrix(test_x))
```

construct the model

```
## xgboost parameters
xgb_params <- list(booster = "gbtree" 
                , objectve = "binary:logistic"
                , eta=0.1 #default 0.3 [0,1]
                , gamma=0
                , max_depth=7 # default 6 Typical values: 3-10
                , subsample=1
                , tree_method = "exact"
                , scale_pos_weight = 5
                , base_score=median(y_train)
                , seed = 2018)

# tuning Cross Validation 
xgbcv <- xgb.cv(params = xgb_params
                , data = dtrain
                , nrounds = 2000
                , nfold = 7
                , print_every_n = 5
                , early_stopping_rounds = 40
                , maximize = F
                , prediction = F
                , showsd = T
                , metrics = "error")

# train model
gb_dt <- xgb.train(params = xgb_params
                , data = dtrain
                , nrounds = xgbcv$best_iteration
                , print_every_n = 2
                , early_stopping_rounds = 40
                , maximize = F
                , watchlist = list(train=dtrain))

test_probs <- predict(gb_dt, dtest, type = "response")
test_preds <- as.numeric(test_probs > .5)

# Change predicted values to match original data set, check accuracy
test_submit <- 0
test_submit[test_preds==0] <- "F"
test_submit[test_preds==1] <- "M"
```

I calculate the confusion matrix

```
caret::confusionMatrix(as.factor(test_submit), test$Sex)
Confusion Matrix and Statistics

          Reference
Prediction  F  M
         F  7  0
         M  7 22

               Accuracy : 0.8056          
                 95% CI : (0.6398, 0.9181)
    No Information Rate : 0.6111          
    P-Value [Acc > NIR] : 0.01065         

                  Kappa : 0.55            
 Mcnemar's Test P-Value : 0.02334         

            Sensitivity : 0.5000          
            Specificity : 1.0000          
         Pos Pred Value : 1.0000          
         Neg Pred Value : 0.7586          
             Prevalence : 0.3889          
         Detection Rate : 0.1944          
   Detection Prevalence : 0.1944          
      Balanced Accuracy : 0.7500          

       'Positive' Class : F
```

How can I improve the sensitivity of the model without decreasing the accuracy? Maybe the key is in `scale_pos_weight` I do not know. Any suggestion is welcome.
**Note:** My interest is to have a model the best balanced. As much as possible classify the largest number of female cats correctly.

Comment: You can't. You have requested the impossible. There is an inherent tradeoff between sensitivity and specificity. "Accuracy" is completely determined by the data and the choice of where you put your cutpoint. Live with it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First use `max_depth = 6` maximum depth of a tree. Now use the following code:

```
library(caret)
k <- seq(0.5,0.99,0.01)
Sensitivity <- rep(0,length(k))

for(i in seq_along(k)){
  test_preds <- as.numeric(test_probs > k[i])
  test_submit <- 0
  test_submit[test_preds==0] <- "F"
  test_submit[test_preds==1] <- "M"
  tab <- confusionMatrix(as.factor(test_submit), test$Sex)
  Sensitivity[i] = tab$byClass[[1]]}

max(Sensitivity)
[1] 0.8571429
pos <- which.max(Sensitivity)

test_preds <- as.numeric(test_probs > k[pos])
test_submit <- 0
test_submit[test_preds==0] <- "F"
test_submit[test_preds==1] <- "M"
```

Calculate the confusion matrix

```
confusionMatrix(as.factor(test_submit), test$Sex)
Confusion Matrix and Statistics

          Reference
Prediction  F  M
         F 12  5
         M  2 17

               Accuracy : 0.8056          
                 95% CI : (0.6398, 0.9181)
    No Information Rate : 0.6111          
    P-Value [Acc > NIR] : 0.01065         

                  Kappa : 0.6063          
 Mcnemar's Test P-Value : 0.44969         

            Sensitivity : 0.8571          
            Specificity : 0.7727          
         Pos Pred Value : 0.7059          
         Neg Pred Value : 0.8947          
             Prevalence : 0.3889          
         Detection Rate : 0.3333          
   Detection Prevalence : 0.4722          
      Balanced Accuracy : 0.8149          

       'Positive' Class : F
```

As we see now, you will have a model with greater sensitivity while maintaining accuracy, so you can classify the female cats with less error. **Note:** However, the price will be less Specificity.

Comment: In fact it is not impossible to increase the sensitivity without decreasing the accuracy, finding the optimal cutpoint.